# Uniqueness of linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra

suppose $A$ and $B$ are linear operators on a vector space such $A(u)=B(u)$ for all $u$ in the vector space. Is it true that then $A=B$? If so, how can we prove it?

Comment: How do you define a mapping?

Comment: Your question is like "We see that the cat eats the bird. How can we prove that the cat eats the bird?"

Comment: If you cannot distinguish $A,B$ then they are the same. Of course, it depends on what equal equals. Lexicographically, $A $ and $B$ are distinct, but functionally they are the same.

Comment: To me this would seem to be a statement that is true by definition? My thoughts:

If you have a linear operator, it can be replaced by a matrix:
$$A(u)=B(u) \rightarrow T_A \vec u = T_B \vec u$$
$$T_A \vec u - T_B \vec u = \vec 0$$
$$ (T_A - T_B) \vec u = \vec 0$$
...
Seems like something to do with the null-spaces. Anyone got ideas?

Comment: I assume the codomains are the same? Otherwise, it is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If $A\neq B$ then there would be a $v$ such that $A(v)\neq B(v)$, but you've already said this is not the case, so$\dots$